# How do I diagnose a temp file "leak"

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Our application has recently started creating (and not cleaning up) temp files at a pretty high rate (though it still takes a couple of days of high use to choke our CI servers when we run out of temp file names).  It's a large application with a large team working on it, so the issue is hard to track down by reviewing commits. Is there a good way to diagnose this sort of problem?

A couple of extra things I've noticed (though they have not gotten me anywhere yet):

- The "leaked" temp files show up in c:\windows\temp, regardless of what %temp% is set to
- They are always empty, as though someone gets them and does nothing

Finally, we recently started using sqlite to store some files locally instead of using the file system directly.  A little searching suggests that SQLite writes some temp files there, but all the forum posts suggest they are massive, where I have 0 bytes files.  Anyone have an experience with SQLite creating a problem like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that is most likely the issue is [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx). Check out if all calls to it delete the resulting temprory file.

Comment: I really hate this answer, because I hate finding problems via code review, especially since our codebase is huge.  However, other tacts I tried did not work, and it was only via code review in a place this had changed recently that we were able to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to watch for the creation of those files and then look at the stack of the calling thread at the time the file was created. That should tell you who's making the files, and then you can watch to see how the files are used, too.

Simply set the filter to include only "Process Name is XXX.exe" (where XXX is the name of your program) and "Path begins with c:\windows\temp".